# How to use escaping with split function in java?

Tags: java, regex

I am implementing a chat system and I am running into a problem while parsing the message.
As part of the message string, I have sending a bunch of key params  like this

> key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3,message:"random text with character : /" etc.

I will later parse this string using split on command and colon. However one of the params is message which can contain both command and colon. so if the message has any of those characters, it will break my parse logic. So is there any way I can escape these characters in the message string? I tried adding two backslashes to escape it but that did not work.

parse code

```
        String[] params = chat.split(",");

    for(String param:params){
        String[]pair = param.split(":");
        if(pair.length != 2){
            String key = pair[0];
            String value = pair[1];
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an example or piece of code.

Comment: why do you need to reinvent the wheel? use some format that already has library support for escaping like json or xml.

Comment: It is possible if the values (value1, value2 ...) have a starting and ending character eg quote: "chat,message;"

Comment: Find a JSON decoder and store it in a `Hash<String,String>` ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun added the sample string and code.

Comment: @Dude Don't you mean `if(pair.length == 2)`?

Comment: @javaHunter: When it is quoted, then it is possible to parse. Just don't use split.

Comment: _message_ is a user input, so when ever you retrieve the input, check if it contains your delimiter (comma and colon). If it exist, replace them all with some special character[s] (very special character). Upon displaying, replace it back

Comment: Something like this: https://regex101.com/r/rQ7tN5/1, in Java, you need to use Matcher loop. However, I personally will use a stronger regex if I design the format myself or use library if it is an existing format.

Comment: You could also use a delimiter from the [unicode private use areas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) and remove all such characters from user input as they shouldn't be in there anyways. Then you don't need to do any escaping. However you might get problems reading messages with other tools.

Answer (score 0):

you question isn't clear i need more example and the best way to receive the messages in JSON format thats makes your job much more cleab but i provide two answers .

For just getting the message as raw( if you are sure that the key value will be "message" and capture everything in the second part):

```
for(String param:params){
        if (param.contains("message")){
            String[] pairs=param.split("message:");
            String key = "message";
            String value = pairs[1];
        }
        String[]pair = param.split(":");
        if(pair.length != 2){
            String key = pair[0];
            String value = pair[1];

        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

return:

> "random text with character : /" etc.

For escaping the special character in string you have to use the following method :

```
 for(String param:params){
        if (param.contains("message")){
            String[] pairs=param.split("message:");
            String key = "message";
            String value = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(pairs[1]);
        }
        String[]pair = param.split(":");
        if(pair.length != 2){
            String key = pair[0];
            String value = pair[1];

        }else{
            return null;
        }
```

return:

> \"random text with character : /\" etc.

you have to import Apache Commons Lang » 3.0 here is the link for maven :
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0